# How to make an ObjectResult filterable

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

It seems like it should be simple, but I'm apparently too dense to figure it out.  I'm getting an ObjectResult using a simple `ObjectQuery`; it's just a few records in the data table.  I assign it to a `CollectionViewSource` Source property.  I then look at the View property of the `CollectionView` and see that `CanFilter` and `CanSor`t are both false.  When I get the DefaultView as a BindingListCollectionView, it shows that the `CanCustomFilter` is false.  Since these are read-only, I cannot change the value(s).  Now I'd like to set a filter (or sort) on the retrieved data without making a trip back to SQL Server, but for the life of me I cannot find a way to get the data with these properties set true.

I tried using `ObjectResult.AsQueryable<T>()` and the result DOES have `CanFilter` and `CanSort` true, but that changes the View type from `System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView` into `MS.Internal.Data.EnumerableCollectionView` and I cannot find a way to cast that `EnumerableCollectionView` back into a `BindingListCollectionView`.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot filter or sort `ObjectResult`. It is not possible because `ObjectResult` can be read only once so if you render it for the first time the result is read and any other operation tying to read it again will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason of such deviation is that `BindingListCollectionView` can't filter or sort any `IQueryable` objects (don't know why), in spite of execution of query on setting `Source property`. The simpliest way is to use `ToList<T>()` method, which executes query, but formed `List<T>` can be sorted and filtered by `BindingListCollectionView`

Comment: Thanks, ASpirin, that does work.  However, once the Source is bound to the results of the ToList<T>(), it is now a ListCollectionView, not a BindingListCollectionView, so the appropriate filtering approach must be taken, i.e., set view.Filter = new Predicate<object>(), and the CustomFilter with its syntax cannot be used.  So while this is a work around, it doesn't answer my question.  By the way, in another control (these are in combo boxes), I used a StyleSelector to do the filtering -- another work around, but not what I'd like to do.

Comment: why you set into filter empty predicate? P.S. ListCollectionView implements the same interfaces as BindingListCollectionView and IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem

Comment: I'm not using an empty filter predicate; I was just indicating that I have to use that filter form (syntax).  The actual entry is      viewType.Filter = new Predicate<object>(filter.FilterSubmittalType);